# NSMutableAttributedString Crashing App

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm doing something wrong with the range (I think) in setting this `NSMutableAttributedString`. Can anyone tell me why this is crashing my program? It looks right to me, but I'm obviously wrong! Thanks.

```
NSString *placeHolderString = @"USERNAME";
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
float spacing = 5.0f;

// crashes on this line
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                         value:@(spacing)
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [placeHolderString length])];

self.userNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString;
```

Comment: It would help if you provided details about the crash including the actual line causing the crash and the complete error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think was causing your issue is that you were never really accounting for your `placeholderString` in the first place. In addition, your value parameter could simply use `numberWithFloat` as the application would then known what type you are using all the time.

Once you account for the `placeHolderString`, you are then going to use the length for the `attributeString`, as it now just contains the contents of your `placeholderString`. Then we just simply copy that string which contains your attribute using the `UITextField` property `attributedText`.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeHolderString];
float spacing = 5.0f;
[attributeString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:spacing]
                        range:(NSRange){0,[attributeString length]}];
userNameTextField.attributedText = [attributeString copy];
```

For more context, attributes like `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` exist and you can do some really powerful things with `NSMutableAttributedString`. Refer to the documentation for options.

Comment: While the code in your answer seems correct, a good answer provides at least some explanation.